# Calculating work in a two dimensional space

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, vectors

I am struggling to understand how to solve the following question:

[image]

I can't figure how to use the integrals properly, and I can't understand how to get rid of the unit vectors. I was given a solution, however there are no explanations in it so I can't understand some parts. Mostly the ones where the unit vectors simply disappeared.

Can anyone provide a full mathematical explanation?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work is

$$
W = \int_\gamma{\bf F}\cdot {\rm d}{\bf r}
$$

The integral is done along a path $\gamma$ connecting the points $(0, 0)$ and $(2,4)$. For example in the first problem, it is suggested to split the path in two pieces, one from $(0, 0)$ to $(0, 4)$ and then from there to $(2,4)$. For the first one

$$
\gamma_1 = \{(x, y) | x = 0 \mbox{ and } 0 \leq y \leq 4 \}
$$

so ${\rm d}{\bf r} = {\rm d}y \hat{\bf y}$ and

$$
W_1 = \int_0^4 [(y^2 - x^2)\hat{\bf x} - 2xy \hat{\bf y}]\cdot {\rm d}y \hat{\bf y} = \int_0^4 (-2xy){\rm d}y = 0
$$

since along $\gamma_1$ we have $x=0$. Now you need to calculate $W_2$ and then add them up $W = W_1 + W_2$.

Similarly you solve the second problem

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you got rid of the unit vectors? Is this because the dot product of  unit vector of y * the unit vector of y gives 1, and unit vector of x * unit vector of y gives 0?

Comment: @איתןלוי yes, that’s the reason

Comment: Please don't answer "do my homework for me" type questions. This isn't a homework help site and answering them only encourages more of these types of questions that we don't want.

Comment: @KyleKanos Thanks for the comment, I'm certain this has been discussed many times over the meta, but what is then the purpose of having a `homework-and-exercise` tag if not to help users get started with the solutions (which is by the way I what I did in the answer)? Or what kind of problems classify as homework then? I truly believe that giving somebody a hint is not the same as solving a homework

Comment: @caverac mostly categorization for people to skip these types of questions and probably also for identifying for possible closure. IMO, giving someone a hint is just as bad as giving a full answer because it still gives the perception that we *are* a HW help site, which is not the case.

Comment: Additionally, *A "homework question" is any question whose value lies in helping you understand the method by which the question can be solved, rather than getting the answer itself.* (From the link I gave to the OP).